# Image looks open exposed while using imwrite on opencv

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to save 16 bit images from ROS bag as .jpg, but where i save them, my images look over exposed, but when I use matlab its saved correctly. I'm not sure where I am screwing things up. My function is shown below.

```
void img_listener::callbackirimage(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg)
{
        ir_img_ptr=cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg,msg->encoding);
        rep_ros_ir_time[ir_image_count] = msg->header.stamp.toSec();
    #ifdef _DEBUG
        ROS_INFO("The reported color image time :%15.15f",rep_ros_clr_time[color_image_count]);
    #endif
        //ir_img_ptr->image.convertTo(ir_img[ir_image_count],CV_8UC1,(double)(1.0/256),256);
        //ir_img_ptr->image.convertTo(ir_img[ir_image_count],CV_8UC1);
        ir_img[ir_image_count] = ir_img_ptr->image;
        if (ir_image_count >= FRAME_RATE_COLOR_IMG)
            ir_image_count=0;
        else
            ir_image_count++;
}
```

where

```
 cv::Mat ir_img[FRAME_RATE_COLOR_IMG];
```

When I perform a imshow  or a imwrite, the resultant image looks over exposed .[image: image description]

as compared to

[image: image description]

Setup: Ubuntu, ros jade, opencv 2.4.8.
Any Help is greatly Appreciated.

Thanks
Akshay

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241623/image-looks-open-exposed-while-using-imwrite-on-opencv/) by [SpacemanSPIFF](https://answers.ros.org/users/22434/spacemanspiff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2016-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

JPG does not support 16 bit images and with OpenCV you apparently need to convert your images explicitly to 8-bit before saving (information will be lost!)

You have commented out code that does almost that. It needs to be:

```
ir_img_ptr->image.convertTo(ir_img[ir_image_count],CV_8UC1,(double)(1.0/256), 0);
```

Notice the last parameter. [Look here for convertTo for details](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html).

---

Originally posted by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) with karma: 789 on 2016-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0